# Proving $\forall y\in \mathbb{R}\, \exists x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2+yx-1=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic

I need some help with an expression I've been trying to prove:

> $$\forall y\in \mathbb{R}\, \exists x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2+yx-1=0$$

I already tried to prove absurd but I did not get conclusive results.

Thanks.

Comment: Given $y\in\mathbb{R}$, are you able to solve the quadratic equation  $x^2 +yx-1=0$?

Comment: That's a quadratic equation that you learn to solve early in high school.

Comment: It might help to pretend that it is not a $y$ but instead to substitute $b=y$.

Comment: It might also help to translate that mathematical sentence into natural language, it may guide you in your investigations: "For any real number $b$, the equation $x^2 + bx - 1 = 0$ has a root".

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that the equation $x^2+yx-1=0$ always has a real solution $x$ for any real number $y$ of your choice.

But that's a quadratic equation in $x$ with discriminant $$y^2-4(1)(-1).$$ Can you conclude the deduction now? (*Hint:* A real square can never be negative.)

Answer (score 1):

For each $y  \in \mathbb{R}$ we need $x$ such that $x^2+yx-1=0$.  Using Shree Dharacharya rule (also known as quadratic formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula)
$x=\frac{-y+\sqrt{y^2+4}}{2}$, it can be clearly seen that we have a real solution to the equation $x^2+yx-1=0$ for each $y \in \mathbb{R}$. So the result is true, you can not find any absurd condition.